# Getting substring from string separated with commas only

Tags: javascript, regex, string

If I have a long string

`8718584449,19630000,24,990,10218828289,840000,3,18,8914098889,2120000,4,108,8720551129,3690000,18,42`

and I can get indexes of

8718584449, 10218828289, 8914098889, 8720551129

via the loop, how would I get sub-strings

19630000,24,990
840000,3,18
2120000,4,108
3690000,18,42

from that long string?

Basically, for every 4 numbers how dynamically to get the 2nd, the 3rd and the 4th numbers only if I know the first number of that 4-numbers substring? For instance, if I don't have 10218828289 then I don't want to get 840000,3,18

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "I can get indexes of"?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Willwsharp I mean I know exactly where those numbers located in the string, so I need to get the following substring after each long number

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.  So you know the indexes of those long numbers you listed and you want to get the next two numbers after each?  If that's the case that seems very odd, there may be a better way to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Willwsharp basically for every 4 numbers how to get 2nd, 3rd and 4th numbers dynamically when I know the first number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to avoid regular expressions.

```
var s = '8718584449,19630000,24,990,10218828289,840000,3,18,8914098889,2120000,4,108,8720551129,3690000,18,42';
s.split(',').slice(1, 4).join(',');    // => '19630000,24,990'
s.split(',').slice(5, 8).join(',');    // => '840000,3,18'
s.split(',').slice(9, 12).join(',');   // => '19630000,24,990'
s.split(',').slice(13, 16).join(',');  // => '840000,3,18'
```

If, for whatever reason, you want to use regular expressions:

```
var s = '8718584449,19630000,24,990,10218828289,840000,3,18,8914098889,2120000,4,108,8720551129,3690000,18,42';
s.match(/\d+,((?:\d+,){2}(?:\d+))/g);  // => ['19630000,24,990', …]
```

[Try it with RegEx101.](https://regex101.com/r/mS9oC2/1)

Comment: You could've put the first solution in a loop.

Comment: For every 4 numbers how to get 2nd, 3rd and 4th numbers dynamically when I know the first number? I want those numbers only if I have the first number. In your example, it looks like it gets every possible scenario, and it is not dynamic

Comment: @KananFarzali I’m not sure I understand. If you want to search for “the three numbers after a specific number”, you can replace the first `\d+` with that number: `new RegExp(x + ',((?:\\d+,){2}(?:\\d+))', 'g')`. Is that what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @thomasd that is perfect! Cheers